# форум asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

В виде практики для самообучения, я решил попробовать сделать небольшой форум. Без каких либо фич и крутых штук. Просто хочу на данных момент сделать возможность создавать темы для авторизированных пользователей ну и собственно писать сообщения  в теме. Однако не могу понять как это правильно сделать. То есть что собой представляет "тема" и "сообщение". Это две сущности у которых есть там например: автор, дата создания, ну и id. Все это должно храниться в БД или другом месте? Или это не совсем сущности. Сделать ли просто две таблицы "тема" и "сообщение" и связать их по общему ключу, чтобы сообщения были привязаны теме. В общем прошу просто направить на верную мысль, что собой являет "тема" и "сообщение". Как это можно правильно реализовать, но в тоже время чтоб было немудрено и понятно. Первый интересный и на мой взгляд реальный какой-то пример, хочу сделать его сам, просто запутался(или не до конца понял), что это все являет собой по частям, и как оно должно работать вместе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зависит от формата форума. Есть две возможных реализации:

- Тема - это отдельная сущность, с отдельным заголовком, состоящая из нескольких сообщений. При отображении сообщения сортируются в хронологическом порядке. Это стандартная схема для форумов.
- Темы, как отдельной сущности нет. У сообщения добавляется поле "Родитель", которое указывает на стоящее над ним сообщение. Похожая схема принята на SO. В списке "тем" показываются те сообщения, у которых нет родителя (т.е. первые в цепочке, на SO это вопросы).

Выбирайте ту, которая вам больше нравится. Если есть сомнения - поищите на github любой опенсорсовый форум и подсмотрите реализацию.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете посмотреть схему данных, которая используется на Stackoverflow.
На странице [Viewing Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/new) справа есть Database Schema со списком таблиц. Можете написать SQL запроc и посмотреть на данные.

Много полезной информации, статьи и примеры есть на сайте [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc)